# Shorter version of IF(ISERROR(...))

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm wondering if there is a way to check if a formula returns an error, and if not, use the value found, *without doing the following*:

```
=IF(ISERROR(A1/B1), 0, A1/B1)
```

The syntax I'm looking for is something like this:

```
=EQ([value_if_not_error], [value_if_error])
```

The solution might contain more stuff, `IF` and `ISERROR` is perfectly fine, as long as I avoid having the main function several times in each cell. The reason why I want to do this is that my equations are quite long and the readability is drastically reduced when I have to write the equation twice, or even more (if several `if`s).

Is there a simple solution to this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
=IFERROR([formula], [value_if_error])
```

Comment: Perfect! I've tried a lot of variations with `IF` using only two arguments, but it turned out to be quite messy... =)